# Зачем нужны разные категории итераторов?

Tags: c++, stl

Зачем реализовывать итераторы типа output или forward если можно просто использовать random access iterator?

Comment: И как вы сделаете random access iterator для `list` или для потока?...

Comment: разве он не используется в list'е?

Comment: он же умеет все что и остальные итераторы

Comment: Он умеет слишком много. Есть случаи, когда ты просто не сможешь удовлетворить его контракт полностью. Для того же потока, например.

Comment: Списки теоретически могут реализовать произвольный доступ, но это будет крайне нерационально. С полным проходом списка на каждый доступ)

Comment: Для каждого алгоритма нужен свой набор свойств, что позволяет использовать их эффективно для разных контейнеров, даже контейнерами не являющихся.

Comment: *"он же умеет все что и остальные итераторы"* Да, но обратное неверно. Итераторы листа умеют не все то, что умеют random-access итераторы.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых не правильно оформлена заголовка вопроса(я позволю себе исправить). Речь ведь не о разных итераторов, а о разных категорий итераторов.

Итератор, это некая абстракция, имеющая конкретные свойства, и одним из этих свойств является его категория. Категория итераторов позволяет проходить по последовательности  каким то конкретным(например стеки, очереди, потоки, списки... ) или произвольным способом (массивы, вектора...).  Эти категории представляют классы, и они нужны для того, чтобы:

- В случае перегрузки, компилятор мог различить алгоритмы, основываясь
  на категории итераторов. Например для того, чтобы определить
  расстояние между элементами, написан обобщенный алгоритм
  std::distance. Но для разных  контейнеров пришлось бы написать
  различные версии алгоритма, а вместо этого написаны можно написать
  перегрузки функции_помощника, имеющий в аргументах категорию
  итераторов(для одних(очереди) вы можете пройти только  операцией `++`
  и результат хранить в счетчике а для других можно просто взять
  разницу указателей), и вызвать эту функцию. И тогда компилятор сам
  определит какую из версий перегрузки вызвать для различных
  контейнеров.
- Использование категорий итераторов позволяет скрыть детали реализации
  за соответствующим интерфейсом. Они дают понятия:    №1 тут можно
  только читать по очереди, №2 это для тех последовательностей, где
  можно только записывать(поток ввода) №3 тут можно и то и другое, а №4
  можно  получить доступ к произвольному элементу. И  эти категории
  подсказывают для каких типов последовательностей написан конкретный
  алгоритм(функция).

P.S.
"Я не могу позволить какому то сотруднику стать директором, пока он не прошел все стадии для получения этой должности..."